# brew link sdl unable to link giving permission denied error

Tags: python, pygame, sdl, homebrew

I couldn't get brew to link `pygame` and when I am trying to install `pygame` I get a permission error

```
$ brew install pygame
==> Installing pygame from homebrew/homebrew-python
Error: You must `brew link sdl' before pygame can be installed
$ brew link sdl
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/sdl/1.2.15... 
Error: Could not symlink share/man/man3/SDLKey.3
/usr/local/share/man/man3 is not writable.
```

From this error message it is not clear what I should symlink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return ownership of those paths to your user account with `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share`.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_TzqzKZpMw thats how I did it. It's confusing at first